# Windows Azure Service Broker

Tags: windows, azure, service, service-broker

is Service Broker implemented to Win Azure SQL databases yet? I found out some articles 2-3 old and its said that it is not implemented yet but it might be in future. So is it?

thanks for response 
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not implemented and there are apparently no plans to do so, as the response to this [5-year-old feedback item](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure) indicates...:

> Today we don’t have a cloud equivalent of SQL service broker outside
>   of either service bus or SQL Server in a VM. I’d love to understand
>   the scenarios that you have in mind. Please send me email at
>   guyhay@microsoft.com if you’d like to continue the conversation.